# Can't update using increment with filtered positional operator in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having problems incrementing a field in the data base using the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[<identifier>]). Here's my structure in the database:

`Schema:`

```
...
funds: [{
    currency: String,
    balance: {
        avaible: Number,
        frozen: Number
    }
}],
...
```

`My query:`

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,{
      $inc: {"funds.$[e].avaible": funds},
      $addToSet: {
        funds: {
          currency: "BTC",
          balance: {avaible: funds, frozen: 0}
        }
      }
    }, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{$eq: {currency: "BTC"}}]}).exec((err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('error', err);
      }
      return console.log(row);
    });
    resolve(data)
  })
  .catch((e) => reject(e))
```

All I want is increment the funds whereas the currency is 'BTC' and if that object doesn't exist create the object.

Where's my fail?

Comment: I'm not sure that mongoose handle the filtered positional operator which is part of mongodb version 3.6. If you have informations about that, I'm interested :) Good luck